# How to expand bootstrap component(container) to full window width and height on initial load and whitch class to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to accomplish exactly something like this:
http://www.freshbooks.com/

I have a container with a background and a form inside it. I want this container to resize exactly to the width and the height of the window it is opened in. Also, when resizing, it should resize along the window.

I drew it so I can be more clear. This is how I want it to look like:

[image]

Instead, at the moment it looks like:

[image: How it looks like at the moment]

I know how to do this with jQuery, it's pretty simple, but if I set a fixed height to the container, the "responsiveness" of bootstrap and of the page is completely lost when I shrink it to a smaller size.

I am pretty sure that bootstrap has some build in and ready to use functionality for doing this, but obviously I can't find it.

Also, I am having trouble to center the "Some text and form" components vertically in the gray area.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should be no need for jQuery or JavaScript. This can be done using only CSS.

You can use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container` to have it span almost the entire width of the window. The columns inside it will have a small gutter of 15px to the left and right though. But as you'll likely add the `background-color` on the `.container-fluid` this shouldn't be a problem.

Put all content that should take up the entire height of the window inside the `.container-fluid` and add a `height` property to it. Either `100vh`, 100% of the view height. If that doesn't work due to browser support (e.g. you need to support IE8) give it a height of `100%` and make sure that all its parents (at least `html` and `body`) also get a `height: 100%`.

```css
.height-full {
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid height-full bg-dark">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Full width and height</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Regular content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it's only about showing a small form horizontally and vertically centered in the entire width and height of the screen, I suggest not using the `.container-fluid` but the regular `.container`. From your screenshots it seems that you don't want the form to take up the entire width of the screen. Surround the `.container` with a `div` that has its `background-color` set.

Create a Bootstrap grid that contains the form (in my example I've used `.col-xs-6.col-xs-offset-3` to have a half width column in the center of the screen. Give this column the `height: 100vh` to make it take up the entire height of the screen. The horizontal centering is now done.

Vertical centering is done by positioning the form absolutely, pushing it down `top: 50%` of the height of its container (the column has `position: relative`) and pulling it `transform: translateY(-50%)` of its own height up. See css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ for more information

The `100vh` might conflict with your navbar. Take it outside of the regular document flow by either make it fixed by adding `.navbar-fixed-top` or position it absolutely.

```css
.height-full {
  height: 100vh;
}
.bg-dark {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.vertically-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 height-full">
        <form class="vertically-center">
          <h1 class="text-center">Some text</h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Regular content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just note that the `row` have a `margin: -15px` which with `container-fluid` it will stretch some contents out of the view.

Comment: I think it won't as the `.container-fluid` has a `padding: 15px` on it. See this blogpost for a brilliant explanation on how Bootstrap's grid works: http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: @ckuijjer thats why the row have `-15` to counter that but it wont and contents will go out of the view because margin over ride the padding in that case ,u can try that with something like `h1` or something and it will do just as i mentioned.

Comment: And that's exactly why you always need to add a column class like `.col-xs-12`. Never use use Bootstrap's grid without understanding you need to have a `.container`, `.row` and a column class

Comment: Hi! So, I tried your code, it works great! But now, I have another problem - as seen on the pics I want these 4 icons that seem like a toolbar  to be placed also on the bottom of the page on first load. I put them in the `.height-full <div>` as a new `container-fluid` and a `row` with `style="bottom: 0; right:0; left:0; position: absolute;"` The result is fine, but the problem is that when shrunk, the toolbar is not responsive and actually covers the form on the top...

Comment: Another problem - as I have multiple components on this div, I can't really use the vertically-center, because not the column is streched, but the <div> with all the components.. Do you know a smarter way to do this thing with the bottom toolbar?

Comment: The easiest way might be to `position: absolute` the fixed height toolbar at the bottom of the `.height-full` container and to add its height as `padding-bottom` to the `.height-full`. Another option would be to play with `height: calc(100vh - 100px)` on the `height-full` for a `100px` high toolbar. I think it'll depend what the frame of reference should be for the vertical centering.